# Setting null date field in django JSON API REST from Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, rest

I'm trying to clear a date field through a REST API call in Django from Javascript.

When running my tests with mock HTTP calls from Django-to-Django it successfully empties the date field:

```
    data = {
        'data': {
            'type': 'items',
            'attributes': {
                'due_date': None,
            }
        }
    }
```

However attempting to do the same thing from Javascript with a Null does not seem to work. The server returns 200 OK but the item still has the original date. Instead of clearing the date field it's simply ignoring the Null.

Is there a different way of doing it through JS?

Cheers

Comment: could you provide your django code where you handle this request? Thanks!

Comment: That seems like a defect in the software you're testing more than a limitation of JS. To me it seems your server doesnt properly parse null vs undefined values in your JSON.

Comment: show more of your code, there must be a difference between the request sent by JS and the request you're using in your Django tests

Comment: We're using Django REST API so most of this is handled automatically by the framework. We have validators which are irrelevant for this question (they pass ok here). I

Comment: @BoboDarph Yes I'm assuming we're doing something wrong. Either null is not a valid value or it's a problem with Django REST API. We're not manipulating the data manually anywhere.

Comment: @Anentropic The different is that from Python we're using 'None' while from JS we're using 'null'. My questions is basically: Is this correct? Is there another way to nullify a Date field in Django from JS?

Comment: What I mean is: when you deserialize a JSON body having `"due_date": null` you will get `'due_date': None` in python. So they are exactly equivalent. so check that you're really sending what you think you're sending. From what you said, you already proved the Django view works.

Comment: Are you using 'Django REST Framework'? No one can answer this question if you don't show your code and what the JS client is sending